# How to use CoCreateInstance in c++

Tags: c++, com

I am a COM beginner. I have a DLL file that I register using the `regsvr32` command. In the COM client, I try to use the `CoCreateInstance` function, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
IMessageBox *pBox;        
hr = CoCreateInstance(
          __uuidof(IMessageBox),
          NULL,
          CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
          IID_IUnknown,
          (void **)&pBox
     );
```

`IMessageBox` is the interface which is defined in my DLL file. It implements the `IDispatch` interface. The result of `hr` displays the error `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`. How do I use the `CoCreateInstance` function?

Comment: The first argument is a CLSID, the guid of the class object you want to create.  Which we don't know but it certainly isn't the guid of the IMessageBox interface.

Comment: To clarify: Say that you want to use an `AcmeMessageBox`, which implements the `IMessageBox` interface. You'd then pass `__uuidof(AcmeMessageBox)` and `IID_IMESSAGEBOX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error tells you what is the problem. The class you are requesting is not registered in the COM registry. It could be that the IID of class that you registered is not the one that you are requesting. Another common failure mode is that you registered a 32 bit DLL and your calling process is 64 bit. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `__uuidof(IMessageBox)` you have to pass the UUID of the class you want to instantiate - i.e. the class you registered previously using `regsrv32`.